# Using Selenium to fill forms from XML file

Tags: java, xml, selenium, automation

**EDIT:** Never mind, I figured it out. Had to do `By.name()` instead of `By.id()`.

I am trying to learn how to use Selenium with XML files but seem to have run into a problem.

Steps:

- I parse the XML file and save the values into strings
- Using Selenium WebDriver, I open up Google and try to insert some value in the search box and hit "Google Search".

This is where I get stuck. The value is never inputted and it never clicks the button.

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<TestData>
    <url-name>
        <url>http://www.google.com</url>
    </url-name>

    <user-details>
        <email>test203@gmail.com</email>
        <phone>(555)5559292</phone>
        <folder>inbox</folder>
    </user-details>
</TestData>
```

Java Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class XMLTest 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        try {
            // Get xml file
            File file = new File("input.xml");

            // Prepare XML
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = db.parse(file);

            String url = document.getElementsByTagName("url").item(0).getTextContent();
            String email = document.getElementsByTagName("email").item(0).getTextContent();
            String phone = document.getElementsByTagName("phone").item(0).getTextContent();
            String folder = document.getElementsByTagName("folder").item(0).getTextContent();

            System.out.println("\n [Debug Info]\n ------------"
                             + "\n Mail:\t\t" + url
                             + "\n Email:\t\t" + email
                             + "\n Phone:\t\t" + phone
                             + "\n Folder:\t" + folder);

            // Selenium code
            WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();

            wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,  TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            wd.get(url);    // Go to URL
            wd.findElement(By.id("q")).sendKeys(phone); // Type into google search box
            wd.findElement(By.id("btnK")).click(); // Click button
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            System.out.println("\n\n [Selenium]\n -----------");
            System.out.println("\n Title:\t\t" + wd.getTitle()
                             + "\n URL:\t\t" + wd.getCurrentUrl());

            wd.close();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The browser opens but it just stays on the Google homepage. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: have you got the solution or not your update is not clear

Comment: I did. Abhi just posted it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'q' and 'btnK' are element names and not Ids. Try this.

```
 wd.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(phone); // Type into google search box
 wd.findElement(By.name("btnK")).click(); // Click button
```